# Facebook behaves weird while sharing my website's urls

Tags: facebook, caching, facebook-opengraph

I have tried everything I could before posting this question here on stack overflow.

I am unable to understand why Facebook doesn't pick up any related information to posts on hellyalol for example title, thumbnails or description.

This is an example http://hellyalol.com/181/my-date/

All the open graph tags are in place as shown by source code but facebook debugger doesn't pickup any open graph tag.

```
<meta property='og:title' content='Will you be my date?'/> 
<meta property='og:url' content='http://hellyalol.com/181/my-date/'/> 
<meta property='og:site_name' content='Hell Ya LOL'/> 
<meta property='og:type' content='article'/> 
<meta property='og:image' content='http://hellyalol.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/fart-exhibit-150x150.jpg'/>
```

Another big confusion is When I change permalinks in WordPress for example my-date to your-date it surprisingly works.

e.g http://hellyalol.com/195/years-ago/ this one is working just fine while you share it on facebook but still debugger doesn't pick any open graph tags :S but still I changed the permalink twice for this post before it could work with WordPress

Can any one help? Thanks a lot :(

Server Details: I am using Lightspeed and using w3 total cache with memcache enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to not miss this in your opening html tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

This is your current html tag - as you see, some parts are missing (or wrong) there:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      dir="ltr"
      lang="en-US"
      xml:lang="en-US"
      xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer. For facebook to work with your blog, you should must have www in front of domain. I changed the domain url from http://hellyalol.com to http://www.hellyalol.com and its working